# How to make if statement with combobox (Tkinter)

Tags: python, if-statement, user-interface, tkinter, combobox

**If statement With Combobox**

I am Making App for Calculating BMI with GUI And I make Combobox For Select Gender like (Male, Female, Child) And You Know that the BMI result (obese or underweight.... ) will Be different Between Male, Female, And Child so I want when the user selects Gender ... if the selected Gender is male will print normal (18-25) And When the user select Gender is the child normal is (14-18) etc... Please help me to do that... My code wrote with python Thanks!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title ("BMI")

        self.label = Label(self.window, text="Enter your wight (kg) ").pack()
        self.kg= StringVar()
        Entry(self.window, textvariable=self.kg).pack()


        self.label = Label (self.window, text="Enter your hight (m)").pack ()
        self.m= StringVar ()
        Entry (self.window, textvariable=self.m).pack ()

        self.label = Label (self.window, text="Enter your Gender ").pack ()
        self.g= StringVar ()


        usertype = tk.StringVar()
        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(self.window,state='readonly',values= 
        ['male','Female','child']).pack()
        self.gender = StringVar()

        self.age = StringVar ()
        self.label = Label (self.window, text="Enter your age ").pack ()
        self.spin=Spinbox(self.window, from_=0, to=100).pack ()


        self.buttontext = StringVar()
        Button(self.window, textvariable=self.buttontext, 
        command=self.calculate).pack()
        self.buttontext.set("Calculate")


        self.bmi_num = StringVar()
        Label(self.window, textvariable=self.bmi_num).pack()

        self.bmi_text = StringVar()
        Label(self.window, textvariable=self.bmi_text).pack()


        self.window.mainloop()

    def calculate(self):

        weight=(self.kg.get())
        weight=float(weight)
        hight=(self.m.get())
        hight=float(hight)
        Gender=(self.g.get())
        age=(self.age.get())
        bmi=float((weight)/float(hight**2))
        self.bmi_num.set("Your BMI is %.2f" % bmi)
        if self.g.get()=="Man":
            if bmi < 18.5:
                self.bmi_text.set ("You are underweight")
            if 18.5 <= bmi < 25:
                self.bmi_text.set ("You are normal")
            if 25 <= bmi < 30:
                self.bmi_text.set ("You are overweight")
            if 30 <= bmi > 30:
                self.bmi_text.set ("You are obese")



App()
```

Comment: First of all, move `pack()` of the `self.combo` to different line. Secondly, use: `if self.combo.get() == 'Man':`.

Comment: What is this supposed to do `30 <= bmi > 30`? I think that you wanted to write `30 <= bmi`

Comment: can You please explain more or write the whole code after edit

Comment: Why did You randomly Capitalize some Words In Your question? It makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

A [`ttk.Combobox`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Combobox.html) accepts a `textvariable` option just like `Entry` (and other) widgets do — you could set that to a `StringVar` named `gender`. Its value will automatically be set when user selects something from the combobox's drop-down menu.

A simple way to tell if the use has made a selection or not is to manually assign a value to it that *isn't* something that's on the menu. In the code below its initial value has been set to `"Select"` which is not one of the values in `GENDERS`.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

MALE, FEMALE, CHILD = 'Male', 'Female', 'Child'
GENDERS = MALE, FEMALE, CHILD


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title ("BMI")

        Label(self.window, text="Enter your weight (kg)").pack()
        self.kg = StringVar()
        Entry(self.window, textvariable=self.kg).pack()

        Label(self.window, text="Enter your height (m)").pack()
        self.m = StringVar()
        Entry(self.window, textvariable=self.m).pack()

        Label(self.window, text="Enter your Gender").pack()
        self.gender = StringVar(value="Select")
        ttk.Combobox(self.window, state='readonly', values=GENDERS,
                     textvariable=self.gender).pack()

        self.age = StringVar()
        Label(self.window, text="Enter your age ").pack()

        Spinbox(self.window, from_=0, to=100).pack()

        self.buttontext = StringVar()
        Button(self.window, textvariable=self.buttontext, command=self.calculate).pack()
        self.buttontext.set("Calculate")

        self.bmi_num = StringVar()
        Label(self.window, textvariable=self.bmi_num).pack()

        self.bmi_text = StringVar()
        Label(self.window, textvariable=self.bmi_text).pack()

        self.window.mainloop()

    def calculate(self):
        weight = float(self.kg.get())
        height = float(self.m.get())
        gender = self.gender.get()
        age = self.age.get()

        bmi = weight / (height**2)
        self.bmi_num.set("Your BMI is %.2f" % bmi)

        if self.gender.get() == MALE:
            if bmi < 18.5:
                self.bmi_text.set("You are underweight")
            elif 18.5 <= bmi < 25:
                self.bmi_text.set("You are normal")
            elif 25 <= bmi < 30:
                self.bmi_text.set("You are overweight")
            else:  # bmi > 30
                self.bmi_text.set("You are obese")

        if self.gender.get() == FEMALE:
            ...  
        
        # etc


App()
```

Comment: The else block will be executed as well if `bmi` < 25.  Change the 2nd and 3rd `if` to `elif`.

Comment: @acw1668: Thanks.

Comment: Adnan mohammed: With the fix suggested by @acw1668, does my answer solve your problem?